# Normal subgroup: a problem in Verification of equivalence

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am familiar with various definitions of normal subgroup. The question I am asking is very trivial one; **about a way of proving equivalence**.

> For a subgroup $N$ of $G$, the following are equivalent: (1) $xN=Nx$ for all $x\in G$. (2) $xNx^{-1}=N$ for all $x\in G$.

My proof: $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ right multiply by $x^{-1}$.

$(2)\Rightarrow (1)$: Right multiply by $x$.

But, the sources (books/notes) I saw verify the above equivalence by

1. showing LHS is subset of RHS in each statement;
2. proving LHS is in RHS by taking element of LHS and showing that it is in RHS.

But, I wonder, isn't it correct, to prove the equivalence in one or two lines  (right multiply by $x$ or by $x^{-1}$ accordingly)?

(In short, can't we avoid "element-belonging" verification for proving equivalence?)

Comment: "Can't we avoid" - it really depends on what you are allowed to use. If the lecture has shown this for cosets, your proof is correct. Otherwise you have to give a proof again, using subset arguments with elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I said everything already. What can you already use about cosets here? That the left multiplication $L_x\colon N\rightarrow xN$ is a bijection? That $xN=yN$ if and only if $x^{-1}y\in N$? And so on. Have a look at your lecture notes.

Comment: The statement $xS=Sx\iff xSx^{-1}=S$ is valid for any subset $S\subseteq G$, one only needs to verify certain straightforward properties like $(xS)y=x(Sy),\ (Sx)y=S(xy)$ and $Se=S$ for the identity element $e$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR The coset notation is really good because it plays nicely with the group operation. However, you need to *prove* that it plays nicely.

---

The strings of letters $xN$, $Nx$ and $xNx^{-1}$ are just notation. They represent specific sets, but there is no reason to think that the group operation plays nicely with these sets. You argument *assumes* that the operation works nicely - for example, that when we multiply every element of $xN$ on the right by $x^{-1}$ we get *precisely* the set $xNx^{-1}$.

Lets write $xN\cdot x^{-1}$ for the set $\{yx^{-1}\mid y\in xN\}$, so your argument is saying that $xN\cdot x^{-1}=xNx^{-1}$. I think it is pretty clear that $xN\cdot x^{-1}\subseteq xNx^{-1}$, but to prove the other inequality we're going to have to think a bit. (Maybe not much, but a bit.)